# How can I prevent a trigerred TNT to explode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was just about to make a self-destruct button under the floor (don't ask me why I make such a dumb thing) and I accidently activated a single TNT.
It is going to explode after 4 seconds, blowing up my structure as there is somehting like 7 TNT block in range.

Is there any way to delay/stop TNT from exploding after it has been triggered?

- I cant use command block because there's only 4 seconds before the explosion.
- I'm on a normal single player map
- I can use commands, cheat is enable

Comment: Welcome on Arqade SE 조원희.
@damadam You should answer in an answer, not in a comment.

Comment: @damadam to me it actually looks like a valid answer, and possibly the only one able to solve OP problem. If it's the fact that it's gonna be a one-line answer that make you don't think it's a valid answer, sometimes answer don't need to be longer than that to be good.

Comment: @Zoma comment posted as answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I've set off some TNT, what should I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27983/ive-set-off-some-tnt-what-should-i-do)

Answer (score 2):

As said in this [link](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360011101772--gamerule-setExplosionDestruction-true-false-), you could try to use :

```
/gamerule setExplosionDestruction false
```

This command would prevent any Creeper / TNT blocks to damage others blocks. If you want to re-enable block destruction, use :

```
/gamerule setExplosionDestruction true
```

NB : You need to play at least at version 1.4.2 Minecraft to have access to `gamerule` command

Comment: After some search, looks like this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27983/ive-set-off-some-tnt-what-should-i-do). As your answer is a good one to me, you should try to answer the previously linked question to keep your answer in an open question.